# Android Create Drawable XML with Image rounded top corners

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to create an Android XML Drawable that I can use as the background for one of my LinearLayouts.  I need the background to have an image, with the top left and top right corners rounded with a 10dp radius.  I've been trying with the code below, but just can not seem to get it working.  Is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">            
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                 android:topRightRadius="10dp">                
        </corners>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bg_navbar_blur" />
</item>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using px instead of dp:

```
<corners android:topLeftRadius="10px"
         android:topRightRadius="10px">                
</corners>
```

EDIT:

This is the complete XML that I am using to round edges in one of my elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="#99000000" ></solid>
   <corners android:radius="8px"></corners> 
   <stroke  android:width="0dp" android:color="#A4C2E0"></stroke>  
</shape>
```

EDIT 2:

I would try this.  Put the image and it's layout (not rounded) in a new XML and place it in a drawable folder.  Let's say it's named linearlayout_bg.xml... In your main layout, create a new LinearLayout and apply this following attribute:

`android:background="@drawable/linearlayout_bg"`

And then use your `<corners` code.  Maybe that'll work?

Comment: But on high density devices you would hardly see the rounded corners as the pixels take up hardly any room.

Comment: Interesting.  I have some rounded edges in a few of my apps.  I'll edit my answer with the complete XML code that I'm using - maybe someone will see something I don't.

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward While the code you provided does create rounded corners, I need to apply them to a XML Drawable that contains an image, not just a solid color.

Comment: @Phil - Yeah, I think that's the holdup.  I think I have an idea.  I'm editing my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a solid element to the shape...

my sample:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#0f0" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Just tried this and it seems to work perfectly

Comment: Just tried using your exact code, but replaced the bitmap src with my drawable image.  No luck.  No rounded corners at all.